# How do I allow a group (except one user in that group) to use sudo without a password?

Tags: password, sudo

How do I allow an entire group, except a certain user in that group, to use `sudo` without providing password?

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to put the user line after th group line:

```
%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
enzotib ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If you want to have many users to be requested the password, without adding them to `/etc/sudoers`, you can create a group just for that, say we name it `dummy`, then write the following

```
%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
%dummy ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

All users in the group `admin` and **not** in the group `dummy` can execute administrative tasks without entering the password.

All users in the group `admin` **and** in the group `dummy` (or only in the group `dummy`) can execute administrative tasks entering the password.

Comment: I need the configuration to work for new users, too, without adding them manually in visudo.

Comment: @traveller You asked how to enable all users in a group except one specific user to sudo to root without being prompted for a password. enzotib answered that question (assuming that you want that specific user to be able to sudo to root, just with a password). Do you want to edit your question?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood the solution given by enzotib. It works. Thank you very much !!

Comment: @traveller: see my updated answer.